# Blank site name when asking a question on a site I'm not registered at

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When I ask a question on a StackExchange site where I'm not registered at, the site name textbox is blank.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed prior to version 1.0, the app now handles asking questions on sites you're not on a lot better. Before this, you could only ask a question on a site you were already registered on so when you entered that view with the context of a different site this issue was created.